# Mounting a Ubuntu 16.04 Server so I can access files/folders liek a normal window/finder

Tags: mount, finder, ubuntu-16.04

I am setting up a local server using Ubuntu server 16.04, using a LEMP stack set up etc. The server will only be accessible via the network for local site dev.

One thing that i'm missing is a way where I can set it up so that on my other machines (MAC/Windows) i can access the sites files/folders, using the normal window/finder and open them up via an IDE to edit directly etc.

Has anyone got advice on performing this, or links that can steering me the in the right way.

I have a current windows machine that is used and mounting to that via a pc or mac is simple and that, but i would like to set it up and a decent / proper server locally.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I discovered webmin(http://www.webmin.com/), and the SAMBA(https://www.samba.org/) option to do exactly what I required, also a good video on this is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDwoDj2cW6c

With a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 during the install (via disk image) you have the option to add SAMBA in the software section, which was  a bonus.

Now i can use webmin but eventually you will end up adding users via the command line.

But after a bit of set up etc was able to connect / mount via my mac or windows